# How to upgrade from 16.04 LTS to 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

How can I upgrade Ubuntu from 16.04 LTS to 16.04.1 LTS? For some reasons, I don't seem to be able to do it. The main reason why I would like to do the upgrade is that the Nautilus shipped with 16.04 is affected by the [zoom problem](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2305478.html).

Just in case someone asks, I have set upgrade to ANY new release and I have issued a `do-release-upgrade` to no avail. Also, the system is fully up-to-date.

If I do `do-release-upgrade -d` then yakkety gets installed and if I restrict to only new LTS releases nothing happens.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

16.04.1 is a point release of 16.04, so you don't need to use the `do-release-upgrade` command, instead:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Will get you there.
In the GUI, just installing all required updates will do the same job. To check that you're on 16.04.1 use:

```
lsb_release -a
```

Comment: I see. But how come I don't get the Nautilus from the 16.04.1? Is it because it would require a downgrade?

Comment: I'm not sure, check which version is installed vs what is available with `apt-cache policy nautilus`.

Comment: nautilus:
  Installed: 1:3.18.5-0ubuntu1~xenial1
  Candidate: 1:3.18.5-0ubuntu1~xenial1
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.18.5-0ubuntu1~xenial1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages

Comment: You've definitely got the most up to date version. I can see that the bug appears to be fixed here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1522316 but it doesn't actually seem to be fixed. Is the problem massive icons? Can you resize them using the GUI?

Comment: I can't make them smaller than they currently are and they are massive. I have installed a fresh 16.04.1 on another machine and the nautilus there has the usual zoom setting in the Edit->Preferences dialog. That's why I was convinced I wasn't using 16.04.1 on my laptop

Comment: Odd, I'm not sure what to suggest, perhaps `sudo dpkg -a --configure` to reconfigure all packages. You may need to ask a different question specifically around the nautilus problem. Mention that you have different behaviour from 2 identical versions with different installs, I installed from 16.04, before 16.04.1 was released, and never experienced the bug.

Comment: I'll try to play around with it a little bit more and if everything fails then I'll ask a specific question. If it helps, I think the problem appeared a couple of days after I have upgraded to 16.04 and not straight away

Comment: I purged nautilus and reinstalled it and it now seems fine (had to reinstall ubuntu-session as well to be able to log in again in case anybody tries this).

Comment: `sudo apt upgrade` or `sudo apt dist-upgrade` says no upgrade available and `cat /etc/lsb-release` still shows `16.04`